# JS - Animated background by tracking mouse

Tags: javascript, mouse, tracking

I would like to make an animated background using vanilla JS and CSS, that tracks the user's mouse movements and rotates a couple of cubes in the background. So basically, if I move my mouse to the right, they rotate from left to right, and vice versa. How can this be done?

Comment: This site is not a coding service. If you want to receive help, add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with regards to what you are looking to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that whit `mousemove` event in JS

Here has a example in jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mr0jas/3zx896og/

I create a cube in 3d (literally) in CSS and transform according the mouse position over the screen

I hope this example solve your problem